# wordpress multisite - handle Database

Tags: multisite, database

I've just recently started using WordPress multisite.

My idea is to use one of my domains to create some sort of "test" place where I can upload my sites for testing.

I will upload here all sites that use WordPress, and so the multisite looked like the best option.

My question now is the following:

I've created some sites, uploaded the theme and installed it, but how can I export the DB for a single site from my local machine and import it to the WordPress multisite live DB? for what I saw, most tables are duplicated and the table prefix is `wp_{{id}}_` meaning that I would have to go and change each one of these to match (possibly) a single site DB structure, is that correct? is there any way/plugin/tool that allows me to do what I want to do easily?

Or, what are the columns that I can export and import safely for WordPress to work?

cause currently I'm manually re-creating all the menus and all the settings for each site, which is definitely not ideal, but with a google search I wasn't really able to find any useful information about how to do this, so I was hoping you can help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: in one domain, there are many sites? so its like sub domains, right?

Comment: you have to create different DB for each sub sites even in one domain

Comment: No not really. Wordpress multisite feature does that for you. The db is already populated and created for each site with the table prefix like i posted above. And yes each site uses a folder structure and not subdomains (http://www.wp.com/site1, http://www.wp.com/site2 etc)

Comment: ahm. your question is about exporting the multisites DB into single DB ?

Comment: No, its about exporting the local (singlesite) db into a remote multisite db but affecting only one site out of all the sites (the exported one)